# How to test if a method was called using nmock3?

Tags: unit-testing, nmock, expectations

I'm trying trying to set the expectation that a method will be called. But when I write the lambda expresion inside the Method method, I get an error because I'm not passing the parameters. I don't care about the instance of the parameters, I only want to know if the method was called. Like the "It.IsAny" from Moq

What should I do?

The C# code: `unitMock.Expects.One.Method(m=>m.Convert());`

Comment: Can you share the code that you have so far? What language is this in?

Comment: There I updated the Question. I just creat the mock object, unitMock, and then try to set the Expectation.

Comment: Can you add code for the method that your are testing? And the entire test method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this question is still actual.
In any case, try to give any parameters to Convert method (just stubs) and add WithAnyArguments.

```
unitMock.Expects.One.Method(m=>m.Convert("")).WithAnyArguments();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to put the method call exactly a number of times:

```
unitMock.Expects.Exactly (2) .Method (m => m.Convert ());
```

At the end you need to call:

```
_mockFactory.VerifyAllExpectationsHaveBeenMet ();
```

To make sure that if you call 2 times and not just 0 or 1.

If you want to establish exactly what data you should call the method:

```
unitMock.Expects.One.MethodWith (m => m.Convert ("5"));
```

If you want to establish what the method should return:

```
unitMock.Expects.One.MethodWith (m => m.Convert ("5")) WillReturn (5);
```